# Using .env variable in VSCode runtimeArgs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger, dotenv

I have a node project and my .env file contains variables including DWAM_STAGE_NAME. I would like to use that variable as part of my launch.json in the following configurations section:

```
      {
    "name": "Debug SST Start",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/sst",
    "runtimeArgs": ["start", "--increase-timeout", "--stage", "${env:DWAM_STAGE_NAME}"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
  },
```

When the above config is run I get --stage "" instead of my expected --stage "MY_VAR_CONTENT"

Unfortunately it seems the envFile is only expanded as environment variables later down the road to make them available inside runtimeExecutable once it's started, but we cannot use the variables in launch.json itself.

Does anyone know a way to use a .env variable in runtimeArgs ?

Thanks.